# How to use Property Let for Arrays?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, properties, getter-setter

I am very new to VBS, but I am not able to implement even the simplest things, as it seems. I want to have a class which holds an array in a private member. Since I want to "inject" the array I tried to implement a "setter-method" using the `Let` functionality.

```
Class CPhase

    Private m_AllowedTasks()

    Public Property Let AllowedTasks(p_AllowedTasks)
        m_AllowedTasks = p_AllowedTasks
    End Property

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        ReDim m_AllowedTasks(0)
End Sub
End Class
```

This class is used as follows:

```
Dim allowed
allowed = Array("task1", "task2")
Dim phase
Set phase = New CPhase 
phase.AllowedTasks = allowed
```

This results in a "Microsoft VBScript runtime error (...) : Type mismatch" in the Let-method. I also tried using different combinations of "ByVal", "ByRef", but since having absolutely no experience with VBS I couldn't find a solution. So what am I doing wrong?

Any hints or links to helpful ressources are very appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is

```
Private m_AllowedTasks()
```

which creates an abomination - a fixed array of no size. Just remove the ().

```
Private m_AllowedTasks
```

to create an (empty) Variant that may be set=let to an useful (redim-able) array.